# Silverlight Out of Browser Questions

Tags: silverlight

I am just getting started with Silverlight. I really like what I see so far. Coming from a Windows background, I have some questions. I'm hoping someone can answer for me.

1. When a Silverlight application is updated, does the entire XAP get downloaded to the user again? Or do only the changed components get downloaded like in ClickOnce?
2. Does Silverlight have support for HTTPS when using out-of-browser mode?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, the Entire XAP gets downloaded again
2. The app does have support for HTTPS services and content if the original page is served via HTTP or HTTPS.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable assembly caching in Silverlight 3 to prevent downloading of system dependencies every time you update your application.

References:

http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/04/06/silverlight-3-s-new-assembly-caching.aspx

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/03/18/silverlight-3-whats-new-a-guide.aspx#asmcache

Comment: This is a great tip, beware that this won't work if you enable Out Of Browser deployment though.